# PHP mcrypt_encrypt differences yet same code?

Tags: php, encryption, mcrypt

So I'm using mcrypt_encrypt in PHP to encrypt some data going into my database.

It's seeming that values it encrypted a while ago are now different to values it's encrypting (for checking) today.

For example...

1234 Was originally encrypted to 4321 and put into the database.

1234 Is now being encrypted again, I expect it to encrypt to 4321 so that it can match the encryption in the database. Except, 1234 is now being encrypted to 2314 so it can't find the 4321 in the database.

The function to encrypt is exactly the same and hasn't changed. The salt is the same.

Is there any reason the following might return different results at different times?

```
trim(base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $salt, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND))));
```

I might add that no matter what it gets encrypted to, they do actually decrypt correctly to the same original value. But that doesn't help with checking the (encrypted) value in the database.

Comment: Please show actual plaintext/encryption examples and not some imagined numbers.

Comment: I can't post private user data on a public site sorry. All I can say is that an email such as 'test.email@test.com' is getting encrypted to two different values. The first being 'VTYYVREbi8RdlEWtfxFBQg6Y0AGsg4h8NeQAJNKKREI='. It will return the same value for a while, and somewhere down the line (I can't give a timeline right now) start returning a different value.

Comment: This code cannot produce two different ciphertexts for the same plaintext, because ECB mode is not randomized (the IV part is completely unnecessary). I suspect there is a problem with the encoding. That's why I'm asking for actual examples. Alternatively, you can give a description how the two ciphertexts differ. Do they differ completely or only something at the beginning or end?

Comment: I'll do some testing using different string encoding and see if this is giving me the results I'm seeing. Many thanks for the clue.

Comment: It might provide valuable clues when you know what your PHP version was before and what it is now. Then go through all of the functions that you use and see if something changed.

Comment: Okay, two things: 1. that's a bad cryptography implementation; please look into using [libsodium](https://pecl.php.net/package/libsodium), [`\Zend\Crypt`](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-crypt) or [`defuse/php-encryption`](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption). 2. Artjom B. is correct; ECB mode is not randomized at all.